# Error while trying to save a product in magento

Tags: sql, magento, syntax-error

Whenever I am trying to make any change in a product and save it in magento backend I am getting the following error.

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') ) AND (p.entity_id = '1696') LIMIT 1' at line 3, query was: SELECT DISTINCT p.entity_id FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `p` INNER JOIN `catalog_product_flat_1` AS `cpf` ON cpf.entity_id = p.entity_id LEFT JOIN `catalog_category_product` AS `ccp` ON ccp.product_id = p.entity_id WHERE ( () ) AND (p.entity_id = '1696') LIMIT 1
```

Kindly let me know what is going wrong and how can I resolve this.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

There is some inconsistency in database catalog_product_flat_1 table, Please empty all flat tables and try. Please take backup before empty the tables.

Comment: Hi @Suman Tried your answer but it did not make any difference.

Comment: Tried That too.